# How to saving in HTML form variables in session?

Tags: php, html, forms, session

I have following form structure for 7 different sites:

```
<div class="row">
<!-- Formular start -->
<form id="formular" action="datenbankanbindung.php" method="POST">
    <!--  Vorschläge für Bedarfe an Mitarbeiterinformation -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header"  data-background-color="purple">
                <h4 class="title">7. Vorschl&auml;ge für Bedarfe an Mitarbeiterinformation</h4>
                <p class="category"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="card-content">
                <!--7.1-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group label-floating optimaler-abstand">
                            <div class="label">
                                <label for="ThemenvorschlaegeFreitagsmail"> 
                                    <div class="aufzählung">7.1
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="beschreibung">Themenvorschl&auml;ge Freitagsmail</div>
                                </label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="ThemenvorschlaegeFreitagsmail" name="name_ThemenvorschlaegeFreitagsmail" rows="1" maxlength="250"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--7.2-->
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group label-floating optimaler-abstand">
                            <div class="label">
                                <label for="AenderungsbedarfeInformationsmedien"> 
                                    <div class="aufzählung">7.2
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="beschreibung">&Auml;nderungsbedarfe in Informationsmedien des Kreises (Internet/Intranet), die nicht &uuml;ber die Beauftragten der Gesch&auml;fts- und Fachbereiche gel&ouml;st werden k&ouml;nnen.</div>
                                </label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="AenderungsbedarfeInformationsmedien" name="name_AenderungsbedarfeInformationsmedien" rows="1" maxlength="250"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--7.3-->
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group label-floating optimaler-abstand">
                            <div class="label">
                                <label for="VorschlaegePressemitteilungen"> 
                                    <div class="aufzählung">7.3
                                    </div> 
                                    <div class="beschreibung">Vorschl&auml;ge für Pressemitteilungen</div>
                                </label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="VorschlaegePressemitteilungen" name="name_VorschlaegePressemitteilungen" rows="1" maxlength="250"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="row">
                    <!--absenden-->
                    <div style="float:right">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="button">absenden</button>
                    </div>
                    <!--Eingaben speichern-->
                    <div style="float:right">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="button" onclick="eingaben_speichern()">Eingaben speichern</button>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>
</form>
```

Now I want store all variables into a session that i can save them into my database at the end of the last site.

The only thing i do was pasting this code at the beginning of each site:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
 $_SESSION['post'][$key] = $value;
 }
?>
```

and in my database.php I pastes this code:

```
<?php
  session_start();
   foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
     $_SESSION['post'][$key] = $value;
   }
  //function to extract array
  extract($_SESSION['post']); 
?>
```

But no variable was pasted into my database.

I have to say that the database and everything works fine because before I made 7 different sites I had one site with all form elements and it worked fine.

Could be this maybe a solution?

```
<?php
$_SESSION['name'] = "wert";
 ?>
```

Do I have to store every name of each form field into a session variable?
Or is there a possibility to do this with a foreach?

EDIT:
This is my database.php. When database.php is executed it wirtes me an empty row in my database.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST; 
    }

    //blendet alle Meldungen (Notizen) aus.
    ini_set('display_errors','off'); 

    //Tabelle Landrat
    //Datenbankverbindung herstellen 
        function Connect()
        {
         $dbhost = "localhost";
         $dbuser = "root";
         $dbpass = "";
         $dbname = "landrat";

        $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die($conn->connect_error);
        //Kodierung auf UTF-8 stellen, da sonst Umlaute falsch dargestellt werden 
        $conn->set_charset("utf8");

        return $conn;
        }

    //Notizen beim Ausführen können vernachlässigt werden -> werden mit obiger Anweisung ausgeblendet
    //Variablen den einzelnen Formlarfeldern zuweisen und mit Datenbank verbinden
        $conn = Connect();

    //Datum
        $date = date("Y-m-d");

    //In welche Tabelle soll alles gespeichert werden? Alle Eingaben in die jeweiligen Spalten schreiben
        $query  = "INSERT into landrat_dashboard (name_Gleitzeitrahmen,name_Abweichungen,name_Mehrarbeitervolumen,name_Mehrarbeit1,name_Ausgleich,name_Mehrarbeit2,name_Personalmassnahmen,
        name_Ueberstunden_abzusehen,name_Klaerungsbedarfe1,name_Klaerungsbedarfe2,name_durchgefuehrt,name_abgelehnt,name_offen,name_Fortbildungsantraege,name_Antraege_genehmigt,name_Antraege_abgelehnt,
        name_Fortbildung,name_Fachbereichsleiterbesprechungen,name_Datum1,name_Datum2,name_Datum3,name_Datum4,name_Datum5,name_Themen, name_Fragestellungen,name_NeueMitarbeiter,name_BekannteFluktuation,
        name_Geschaeftsverteilungsaenderungen,name_Raumplanung,name_Verwaltungsverfahren,name_ITEinsatz,name_Kooperationen,name_ProjekttitelA,name_ProjektverantwortlicheA,name_ZeitplanA,name_BudgetA,name_ProjekttitelB,
        name_ProjektverantwortlicheB,name_ZeitplanB,name_BudgetB,name_ProjekttitelC,name_ProjektverantwortlicheC,name_ZeitplanC,name_BudgetC,name_ProjekttitelD, name_ProjektverantwortlicheD, 
        name_ZeitplanD,name_BudgetD,name_ProjekttitelE,name_ProjektverantwortlicheE,name_ZeitplanE,name_BudgetE,name_Kreisentwicklungskonzept,name_Kooperation1,name_Kooperation2,name_StatusberichtA,
        name_StatusberichtB,name_StatusberichtC,name_StatusberichtD,name_StatusberichtE,name_Fallzahlenentwicklungen,name_Haushaltsansaetze,name_AnzeichenAbweichung1,name_OffeneForderungen,
        name_Kreistag,name_AnzeichenAbweichung2,name_SonstigeVeranstaltungen,name_ThemenvorschlaegeFreitagsmail,name_AenderungsbedarfeInformationsmedien,name_VorschlaegePressemitteilungen,datum) 

        VALUES('" . $name_Gleitzeitrahmen . "','" . $Abweichungen . "','" . $Mehrarbeitervolumen . "','" . $Mehrarbeit1 . "','" . $Ausgleich . "','" . $Mehrarbeit2 . "','" . $Personalmaßnahmen . "','" 
            . $Überstunden_abzusehen . "','" . $Klärungsbedarfe1 . "','" . $Klärungsbedarfe2 . "','" . $durchgeführt . "','" . $abgelehnt . "','" . $offen . "','" . $Fortbildungsanträge . "','" 
            . $Anträge_genehmigt. "','" . $Anträge_abgelehnt . "','" . $Fortbildung . "','" . $Fachbereichsleiterbesprechungen . "','" . $Datum1 . "','" . $Datum2 . "','" . $Datum3 . "','" 
            . $Datum4 . "','" . $Datum5 . "','" . $Themen . "','" . $Fragestellungen . "','" . $NeueMitarbeiter . "','" . $BekannteFluktuation . "','" . $Geschäftsverteilungsänderungen . "','" 
            . $Raumplanung . "','" . $Verwaltungsverfahren . "','" . $ITEinsatz . "','" . $Kooperationen . "','" . $ProjekttitelA . "','" . $ProjektverantwortlicheA . "','" . $ZeitplanA . "','" 
            . $BudgetA . "','". $ProjekttitelB . "','" . $ProjektverantwortlicheB . "','" . $ZeitplanB . "','" . $BudgetB .  "','" . $ProjekttitelC . "','" . $ProjektverantwortlicheC . "','" 
            . $ZeitplanC . "','" . $BudgetC ."','" . $ProjekttitelD . "','" . $ProjektverantwortlicheD . "','" . $ZeitplanD . "','" . $BudgetD .  "','" . $ProjekttitelE . "','" 
            . $ProjektverantwortlicheE . "','" . $ZeitplanE . "','" . $BudgetE . "','" . $Kreisentwicklungskonzept . "','" . $Kooperation1 . "','" . $Kooperation2 . "','" . $StatusberichtA . "','" 
            . $StatusberichtB . "','" . $StatusberichtC . "','" . $StatusberichtD . "','" . $StatusberichtE . "','" . $Fallzahlenentwicklungen . "','" . $Haushaltsansätze ."','" . $AnzeichenAbweichung1 . "','" 
            . $OffeneForderungen . "','" . $Kreistag . "','" . $AnzeichenAbweichung2 . "','" . $SonstigeVeranstaltungen . "','" . $ThemenvorschlägeFreitagsmail .  "','" . $ÄnderungsbedarfeInformationsmedien . "','" 
            . $VorschlägePressemitteilungen . "','" . $date . "')";


        $success = $conn->query($query);

    //Bei Error
    if (!$success) {
        die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);
    }

    //Verbindung zur Datenbank schliessen
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: You seem to be setting the session twice and not reading it? surely if you are going to use it, your db.php file shouldn't need to be setting it again

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if form was sent.

```
session_start();
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST; // no foreach needed
}
```

Comment: And when i have more variables I do this?
session_start();
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST; // no foreach needed
    $_SESSION['post2'] = $_POST; 
.....
}

Comment: which variables? All keys from `$_POST` are saved into `$_SESSION['post']`. Other `$_SESSIONs` stays unchanged. Try this code and add `print_r($_SESSION['post']);` after. You can assign whole array as I wrote.

Comment: Ok i tried it out but there is no value stored in my db again.
I have insert this at beginning in my database.php as you said:
session_start();
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST; 
}

Maybe it is because of my sql query. if the name of a textfield is "name_textfield" i can call it with the same name in my database.php?
....VALUES('" . $name_textfield . "','" ...

Comment: @CK2513: You didn't show us a SQL query. Just saving to session without checking whether form was sent before. If you want to save values from form into databse directly, you don't need to save them into session before. Update your question and show SQL query (with databse structure), than I edit my answer to better fit your situation.

Comment: I updated my post. Database structure is fine as I said it worked when i have one single form-page page which is not divided into a multiple form-page sites. If you need it let me know. Thank you!

Comment: @Ck2513: You just need to work with existing variable in you SQL query. As example I take last two values from SQL query, columns `name_AenderungsbedarfeInformationsmedien, name_VorschlaegePressemitteilungen` and values are `$_SESSION['post']['name_AenderungsbedarfeInformationsmedien'], $_SESSION['post']['name_VorschlaegePressemitteilungen']`. Similarly for other column values. Keys in `$_POST/$_SESSION['post']` arrays has to be same as values or `name` attributes in your HTML elements.

Comment: I print the session out with print_r($_SESSION['post']); but i noticed that only the session variables from the last page were shown. So how can i save all session variables over my 7 sites so that on the last site are all collected? That should be the problem why I get only a blank row in database.